# Highcharts line graph, not starting from far left

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

Trying to move the first line to always come out on the far left and to have the time intervals to start from that point and increment hourly from that point. 
[Example of current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEU3Z.png)

Comment: add fiddle example to show problem

Comment: Set xAxis.min to the first value of the series http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min and set [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval) to 1 hour